# Scrolling div without fixed height

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, scroll

I need to build a dynamically-resizing scrolling div.

The div should dynamically resize to fit the screen. But if the content doesn't fit on the screen, it should display a scrollbar. So the browser's own scrollbar should never need to become active.

I can get a scrollbar to appear in the div by placing another div inside it and using `overflow: auto`.

```
<div id="gridcontainer" style="overflow:auto;height:300px; width:100px;" >
    <div id="gridcontent" style="height:100%">
    <!--Put loads of text in here-->
    </div>
</div>
```

The trouble is that this only works when the first div has a fixed height. I had hoped I could just set the first div to `height:100%`, but sadly not- this property appears to get ignored, and the scrollbar just doesn't appear.

I have tried putting the divs in a table with `height:100%`, and setting the first div to `height:auto`, hoping it might take its height from its parent. But the div still seems to ignore the height property.

So my question is: Can this be done using just html, or- failing that- javascript?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could [stretch the div using absolute positioning](http://alistapart.com/article/conflictingabsolutepositions#section4). This way it will always take the size of the browser window (or the closest, positioned ancestor).

Given this HTML:

```
<div id="gridcontainer"></div>
```

the CSS should be something like:

```
#gridcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/LXRcq/)

Comment: Looks like absolute positioning is the answer. I'm indebted to you :-)

Answer (score 9):

Since IE9 you can use viewport units.

Let's say that the height of your container is dynamic, unless its size is greater than the window height. In that case we stop the expansion & activate the scroll.

```css
#container{
  background: #eaeaea;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div{
  outline: 1px solid orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your method, it saves me hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make element fit the screen then you can set the value of hight and width of the element to 100%.

You will also need to set the height of html and body

```
html, body {height: 100%}
#gridcontaine {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }
```